# Changing ArcMap Display Order of Elements in Same Layer File?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, arcgis-10.5, draw-order

I have a bunch of polygons in a layer file and I want to reorder those polygons so one of them is "sent to back". I am using ArcMap 10.5.

Comment: The only reliable way to do this for certain is to create a second layer, with a definition queries to specfy the "back" features and "front". Due to spatial indexing and other quirks even an ORDER BY might be violated in rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Advanced symbology tool Symbol Levels as discussed a bit here: [[How to force polygons to the bottom, without compromizing drawing speed?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23549/how-to-force-polygons-to-the-bottom-without-compromizing-drawing-speed][1])
Go to Symbology tab, Advanced, Symbol Levels. Click on the use symbol levels box, then move the polygons up and down to control drawing order. However, if you have a lots of ones needing to go back because they are larger, I would do two layers based on a definition query on size (as Vince suggested).